# Do you need import statements in non-driver classes?

Tags: java, class, netbeans, import

I am starting to learn how to use Netbeans so I can learn to create GUIs, but I saw that in the classes of my program the java.util classes throw a "could not find symbol" error in Netbeans.

That makes me wonder: do I need to import java.util (and other APIs like javax.swing or java.io) in all classes of the program, or just the driver class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it needs to be imported in all `.java` files where it is being referred by *non fully qualified* name and it is not implicitly available (for example java.lang.* )

---

**See**

- [Using package member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)